# Circuit design options for 58V lithium battery charger

Tags: battery-charging, pwm, boost, current-limiting, voltage-doubler

I have an Echo 58 volt chainsaw and the battery charger has malfunctioned so that it no longer charges the battery pack. I have been charging it by using a 2A current limited lab power supply set to 58V, and it will charge the battery in a few hours. As the voltage approaches the 58V limit, the current drops off and the charge indicator on the battery indicates a full charge.

The circuit board in the charger is a rather complicated affair that has white silicone globs on many of the components, making it near impossible to troubleshoot. So I would like to design and build a near equivalent circuit, with a sufficient degree of reliability and safety, considering the danger of overcharging and excessive discharging. There is a protection circuit built into the battery, but I think it mostly limits discharge current and shuts off when discharged to a safe level, and I don't want to rely on it.

My first thought was to use a 24 VAC 4 A transformer (I have several), and use a voltage doubler to get about 65 VDC open circuit, which drops to less than 58 VDC with a load of 1 or 2 amps, but I would still need to make sure it does not exceed 58 V when the battery is fully charged. So I came up with a linear regulator using an op-amp, and various high side current limiting means. This would work, but a successful simulation wound up being less than simple, and I'd need to order some 4700 uF 100 V capacitors.

One of the simulations:

[image: 24 VAC 58 VDC Doubler Charger]

However, there were some problems with that design, so I decided to try a boost switching regulator, which could use the 32 VDC nominal full wave rectified voltage and get the required 58 VDC. I may use a PIC microprocessor for the final design, but I was able to get a fairly good circuit simulation using just two op-amps for the PWM and regulation. Here is the circuit:

[image: 24 VAC 58 VDC Boost Charger]

I will probably use a separate 120 VAC to 12 VDC 3W PSU for the 12 VDC instead of the simple zener regulator, because I also need to power a 12 VDC 250 mA fan.

Using a PIC processor will provide options for displaying charge voltage and current, as well as possibly using the same design for a 48 VDC charger (for four 12 V 12 A-h SLA batteries in series). I might actually make a PC board for this circuit, rather than a proto-board assembly.

I think this simple constant current voltage limited design will be OK for the lithium battery. Comments and suggestions for improvement are welcome. Thanks.

(edit) Details about the battery, its protection circuit, and how to reset it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnC-oackhIE

He said the protection circuit does not have balancing. The circuit board has pads and tracks for the resistors and transistors, but they are not populated. There are 14 cells in series, so 58 V is 4.14 V per cell. The protection circuit probably still functions to inhibit additional discharge if any cell drops below a safe level.

What I should do is open the battery and measure the cells to see what their state of balance is, and I could then manually balance them. Bottom balance is probably easier and quicker.

Also, maybe I should try to reset the processor and try using the charger again. I have removed the PC board from the charger, but left the wires so they can be reconnected.

Here are some pictures of the charger PC board:

[image: Echo 58V Charger]

[image: Echo 58V Charger]

[image: Echo 58V Charger PCB]

Comment: If you are charging to the full specified, usually 4.2 V per cell, you need a low current cutoff as well.

Comment: Does the battery have a balance circuit? If not, you'll need to build one into the charger.

Comment: The battery has a protection circuit but I don't know if it has balancing. I found a video that showed the guts of the battery pack and explained how to reset the module: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnC-oackhIE.

Comment: Eight smoked batteries and $500 in parts later........  seriously, just buy a replacement charger from the manufacturer.

Comment: They don't seem to be available new, as they have apparently changed the design. I found a couple used units on eBay for about $50, but they may also fail.